# Is the reply B to question A lexically correct?

Tags: sentence-construction

This is the scenario:

> A. Sorry, I didn't lock the door. 
>  
>   B. I'll solve it. (intended to say: *"Don't worry! It is not a big deal you are afraid of, I solve this issue by just going and locking the door that has been left open!"*)

Is there any idiom in English to use as a reply to A?

Answer (score 2):

You did not define the context. Without context, here is what I understand.

The reply does not sound natural to me. You solve mysteries, puzzles, sum, problems etc. *Locking the door* generally does not belong to any of them!

> Sorry, I didn't lock the door. 
>   Don't worry, I'll do it! (Your sentence seems filled with superfluous words especially when the context is not clear that why was s/he afraid locking the door).

I'll edit my answer if you make your question clearer.

Comment: +1 "I'll do it" is good. "I'll take care of it" is often heard in the US.

Comment: @StoneyB I see. I learned this.

Comment: What about "I'll get this"? @StoneyB

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng "I'll get it" is more likely; *this* would be called for if there were two or more problems and you're indicating which you'll take care of.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is! This occurs commonly, as you suspected.  The common idioms are:

- I got it. (or the variation "I'll get it.")
- No problem [I got it].
- Don't worry, I'll get it.
- I gotcha covered.<sup>1</sup>

<sup>Credit to Jim in comments.</sup>

Comment: and even more informally, "I gotcha covered"

Comment: ... or more formally (and more British) "Don't worry, I'll deal with it"